# Minimum reprocessing when comparing 2 identical list in c#

Tags: c#

I've got two identical lists I need to compare so I thought I'd create a 2 dimensional array and store a bool value as to whether my condition passed or failed but I want to reduce the number of checks made against each element as it wouldn't make sense to:

```
a) compare the exact same elements (as this condition would always pass 
   in my scenario).

   |0|1|2|
----------
 |0|x| | |
 |1| |x| |
 |2| | |x|
----------

b) compare exact opposite elements in the array where if a condition
   passed where i=1 and j=2 we'd know that i=2 and j=1 would also pass.

   Array1: [2,6,9]
   Array2: [2,6,9]

   |0|1|2|
----------
 |0| | | |
 |1| | |p|
 |2| |p| |
----------

 Where p[2,1] would be (9,6) for example and p[1,2] would be (6,9) which
 in my case would mean they are identical.
```

So based on the above is there a way to minimize the looping required or do I have to loop using something similar to this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < compare.Count; j++)
{
    if ((i != j) && 
            !alreadyProcessed[i, j] && !alreadyProcessed[j, i])
    {
            alreadyProcessed[i, j] = true;
            alreadyProcessed[j, i] = true;
            bool condition = ...;
            if (condition)
            {
    }
        }
    else
        {
            if (i == j)
            {
        alreadyProcessed[i, j] = true;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

I was hoping that using linq and intersection for example that I could exclude the likes of (0,0), (1,1) and (2,2) for example and then somehow have a single combination of unique combinations as we would only need (0,1) and (0,2) and (1,2) as we'd know that (1,0), (2,0) and (2,1) would be the same as their opposite.

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since at any point `i` you can disregard everything in the list with an index smaller than `i` (equal would be the same element and smaller, we will already have checked), you can simply go with the following:

```
var array = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};

for (int i = 0; i < array.Count(); i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < array.Count(); j++) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Comparirf {i}:{array[i]} and {j}:{array[j]}");
    }
}
```

Linq doesn't really have the tools to do this efficiently (as far as I know at least).

Comment: You're bang on! I should have spotted that with the inner loop but at least that's better than what I have a the moment. As for linq, it's not a show stopper to be honest. I just like using it when possible :).

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the sequence is identical you are really talking about single sequence.

Below is a working sample of how to use LINQ to get the unique combinations from a sequence.

If you wanted to see if the pairs were equal, you could do

```
pairs.Select(p => p.First.Equals(p.Second));
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X9JuOk), below is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var pairs = ((IEnumerable<int>)new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }).Pairs();
        Console.WriteLine(
            string.Join(
                $",{Environment.NewLine}", 
                pairs.Select(p => $"{{first:{p.First}, second:{p.Second}}}")));
    }
}

public static class Ext
{
    public static IEnumerable<Pair<T>> Pairs<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return source.SelectMany(
            (value, index) => source.Skip(index + 1),
            (first, second) => new Pair<T>(first, second));
    }

    public sealed class Pair<T>
    {
        internal Pair(T first, T second)
        {
            this.First = first;
            this.Second = second;
        }

        public T First { get; }

        public T Second { get; }
    }
}
```